# std::gcd does not compile in g++ 5.4.0 -- 'gcd' is not a member of 'std'

Tags: c++, g++, std, c++17, greatest-common-divisor

Environment:

- Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit
- g++ version 5.4.0

This is the code:

```
#include <numeric>
...
auto g = std::gcd(10, 4);
...
```

I have turned on the `-std=c++17` option in the compiling command:

```
g++ -m64 -std=c++17   -c -g -w -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o main.cpp
```

Then I got the error:

> error: 'gcd' is not a member of 'std'

From [this webpage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/gcd), `std::gcd` is introduced since C++17.

From [this webpage](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html), my version of g++ supports C++17.

But why is there still an error? The same code compiles without any error in Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: You're looking at the language features page. You need to look at the [library features support](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2017)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::gcd` is available from GCC 7.1 onwards only.

From [Table 1.5. C++ 2017 Implementation Status](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2017)

[image]

See conformance viewer for multiple [GCC versions](https://godbolt.org/z/PEMLvY).